# How to display dates between a range columnwise

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have data structured in the following format:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| Case_Number|Start_Date |End_Date   |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
|A1          | 12/1/2017 | 12/15/2017|
|A2          | 12/12/2017| 12/28/2017|
```

I was hoping to transform the Start and End Data into columnwise values using values from a second table that will round down the value to the beginning of the week. For example `12/1/2017` would be rounded down to `11/27/2017` which corresponds to a Monday. Doing this transformation, I was hoping to get the data in the following format:

```
 +----------------+-----------+
 | Week Start Date|Case Number|
 +----------------+-----------+
 |11/27/2017      | A1        | 
 |12/4/2017       | A1        | 
 |12/11/2017      | A2        | 
 |12/18/2017      | A2        |
```

I am hoping to display the first Monday of each week that the case has been active. If the case is closed in any given week, we do not want to display that week in the second table that is generated.

Comment: Please be specific about how you're going from the first during the second table. I have no clue about how your transformation works. Where does `14/4/2017 | A1` come from?

Comment: This date would be the rounded down date of the Monday of that week. I have created a helper table that contains the date for all Monday's of the year. So for as long as the case is not closed in that week, we want to display the Monday date for that week in the second table.

Comment: Looks like you have two separated question. One transform the date and the other `UNPIVOT` the table. I suggest you forcus on only one question because are different topics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good if your helper table with each week starting at Monday also had another column for that date plus 7 days, but if not this should work:

```
select datatable.case_number, helper.week_date
from helper
left join datatable on datatable.end_date >= helper.week_start
   and datatable.start_date < dateadd('d',7,helper.week_start)
```

Note the logic for this comes from the relationship of the dates that may seem "back to front"

```
    W1       w2
s-E |        |        ignore
 s--|--------|-E
  s-|---E    |     
    s----E   |     
    | s---E  |     
    |   s----E
    |     s--|-E
    |        | s-E    ignore
      s < w2
      E >= W1
```

The first and last rows of that "image" do not have any involvement in the period `W1 to w2`, so they get ignored. All the other rows do have some involvement in the period `W1 to w2` so we want to cater for all those conditions but not the others. All positions `s` that we want are `< w2` and all the positions `E` that we want are `> W1` , but for all the rows we want to ignore one of those conditions is untrue. So for all the rows we want: `s < w2 and E > W1`

Comment: Thank you, will try this tomorrow morning and update you!